# Cell showing decimal but Formula Bar showing Percentage

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have never seen this before.

I have decimals entered into the cells. I changed the formatting of the cells to PERCENTAGE, however the cells remain decimals, but it now shows percentages in the Formula bar. I have never seen this before.

If I change the formatting of the cells to text, it changes the Formula bar back to showing the decimals. Then when I change back to PERCENTAGE, it only changes the formula bar but not the cells. It does this anywhere on the page, but if I try to enter in on a new sheet it works fine.

Obviously, I can just copy and paste values to a new sheet and make it work, but I want to know what is happening here

Comment: It's quite interesting ,, if possible please share the Workbook over the network so that me & other can examine the issue to fix it.